# Loading Data using LookUp Transformation in SSIS is taking more time?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, lookup, msbi

I am Loading Data from one server to another through Dataflowtask in SSIS, I have used LookUp Transformation on one column , initially it was very fast loading the data , but when i am running everyday it is taking longer and the outputs are OLEDB Destination and OLEDB Command , The data is around 90K. Any help how can I make it work faster ?

Comment: How long does it takes now and how long it would take before? 90k is not too much. One possibility is that the data volume has increased significantly since the first time you created the package.

Comment: Instead of using lookup transformation, use a SQL script for a stored procedure which will be much faster than lookup transformation.

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL Script in the Source , and i just added lookup transformation on one column

Comment: When I run Initially it has taken 3 mins to load the data , when i am running on daily basis it is taking around 14 mins time, and even there is no sign of data increase

Answer (score 0):

Initial thought would be to change the caching mode on the lookup table. If that helps, you are golden. If not, I would also want to look at what other operations are being performed on the database when that lookup is being performed.

Also, would adding an index to the lookup column be of any benefit? These are just the starters.

Comment: I have Added Index on the Lookup column there is no use, and presently the lookup is in full cache mode , when i am changing that it was taking longer too.